# Is there anything like OneTab available for Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

I am looking for a "tabs decluttering" app for Safari like [OneTab](http://www.one-tab.com) Chrome Extension

> How OneTab Works
>
> Whenever you find yourself with too many tabs, click the OneTab icon
> to convert all of your tabs into a list. When you need to access the
> tabs again, you can either restore them individually or all at once.
>
> When your tabs are in the OneTab list, you will save up to 95% of
> memory because you will have reduced the number of tabs open in Google
> Chrome.

Comment: You could try and contact the developer and see if they could port it to Safari. It should be possible and hopefully not too difficult since they have most of the code already.And the are soon releasing a Firefox version. They have a "We love to hear from you - contact us" at the bottom of their home page

Comment: Just as an update to this question, in the new Safari you can press shift+command+\ to see a list of all your tabs. This probably doesn't affect the memory usage.

Comment: Yes its available now. https://apps.apple.com/in/app/onetab/id1540160809?mt=12

Answer (score 9):

Here is a native way of doing it without the use of any extensions.

In Safari, under the "Bookmarks" menu, there is an option for you to "Add Bookmarks for These X Tabs...". If you click on it, you will be prompted to save these tabs in the current windows as bookmarks. You can assign them to a Folder and give it a Session Name.

[image]

When you do want to resume the session, you simply go to the bookmark folder, right click on it and select "Open in New Tabs".

[image]

The beauty of this methods is that, if you have iCloud sync enabled, you will be able to resume your saved sessions across all your Apple devices.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can reopen the folder of bookmarks on iOS by long pressing it. And, as of iOS 13, you can save all open tabs as a folder of bookmarks by long pressing the bookmarks icon.

Answer (score 6):

There is one now called TabLister, that's very similar to OneTab.
http://tablister.com

Also [available](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.paulgriffinpetty.tablister-54DM2A49PR) from the Safari Extensions Gallery.

Comment: It would be nice if TabLister removed links from the list when I click on them to open them. It makes no sense to retain the link in the list, if I have it open on a tab. This is the way OneTab does it, by the way. Do they take feature requests?

Comment: @Kevin Suttle How do you use tab lister?  I installed it but can't find how to save tabs.

Answer (score 5):

The closest extension that can save the open tabs into a list is [Sessions](https://sessions-extension.github.io/Sessions/).

You can also restore all the tabs all at once, or by double-clicking them to restore individual tabs.

Generally, after you save the tabs into list, you can close the rest of the tabs with <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Closing these tabs will free the memory that the tabs has taken. Meanwhile, your saved list of of tabs are stored in a document that won’t need memory to stay in use. The only time you’ll see the memory usage is when the Session extension is called (which get loaded with the list of the sessions you’ve saved).

Here is the comparison of the memory usage before and after all tabs are closed.

**Before**
[image: Session Before Closing Tabs]

**After**
[image: Session After Closing Tabs]

Comment: Could you add a review? For example, performance aspects: extension memory usage vs memory "released" by saving the open tabs?

Comment: @PauloOliveira read the answer again.

Comment: It's really visible the improvement... ;)

Comment: Is it too paranoid of me not to want to try this? First off, it's not listed in the Safari Extensions Gallery. Second, the developer is completely anonymous and, despite hosting the site w/github.io, has neither code nor a human identity on github.com.

Answer (score 2):

Like I stated under another question, I have had the same question and found no answer. The old extensions mentioned by other answers work no more with the new APIs (Safari 12). So I myself developed a Safari extension named [Tab Space](http://yuanzhoucq.github.io/Tab-Space) which could handle this task for me. To some extent, it provides even more functions, such as adding tags for these saved sessions.

Try it if you'd like to do so.

Comment: ^ costs $0.99, and you can’t build from the github repo.

Comment: I have to say, this looks great. I'll report back.

Comment: Purchased it but it doesn't sync sessions. If you add or close a tab, it won't be reflected in the so called " session" . So it is mostly the same as a bookmarks folder (as Oct 2020)

Answer (score 2):

OneTab for Safari is available via the AppStore https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/onetab/id1540160809

Answer (score 1):

Toast (free), available for Safari and Chrome does this.

https://dotoast.com

You have to reopen the whole session rather than cherry pick tabs to reopen.

Comment: When I tried installing app I saw a message on the site telling me Toast read personal info like credit card numbers if availed on you or other open web pages.  Sounds fishy to me but maybe it's just me.

Comment: @jmh that's standard Safari Extension terms and conditions for anything that has to work on "all pages". Feel free to read up on that. All other extensions listed in these answers have the same caveats. Although they *could* read that information Mac App Store makes sure that they don't.

Comment: ok. That makes me feel better.  I checked it out and saw that it showed up on other extensions as well.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score -1):

In Safari, you have to use the menu View or the Shift+Cmd+\  keys.

Comment: That’s not the same thing.